# wildfly - use CDI with POJO

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I would like use CDI with POJO.

Now have a Jaxrs Resteasy webapp running in Wildfly 10.1.0.Final.

There is a singleton which returns a ServiceImpl class:

```
public class ServiceFactory {

    private static Service service = new ServiceImpl();

    public static Service getEnvsApi()
    {   
       return service;
    }
}
```

And I would like use CDI inside ServiceImpl class

```
public class ServiceImpl extends Service {

   @Inject
   private MyData    myData;

   @Override
   public MyData getData()
   {
      return myData;
   }
}
```

but `myData` is always null.

Have I to start Weld manually?

Answer (score 1):

If your webapp is running in Wildfly you do not need to "start" Weld. Just use CDI API in your code and add `beans.xml` in webapp/WEB-INF (take a look at bean discovery mode of CDI) and CDI will be activated.

Regarding your problem, the problem is you instantiate Service via new operator which breaks CDI! Ss said in others answers, you must use `@ApplicationScoped` on the `ServiceImpl` and you do not need `ServiceFactory`.

Just declare ServiceImpl as `@ApplicationScoped`

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

   @Inject
   private MyData    myData;

   @Override
   public MyData getData()
   {
      return myData;
   }

}
```

And then you can `@Inject` your `Service`:

```
@Inject
private Service service
```

Answer (score 0):

You also must inject the Service in the ServiceFactory because if you instantiate it it is not under CDI control.

Probably you can completely remove the ServiceFactory and inject the Service everywhere you need it.